# What is the best place to discuss about a particular book on mathematics?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering if anyone knows where the best place to discuss about a particular book on mathematics. Thank you!

Comment: There might be a suitable topic for general discussion involved here, but a brief one-liner is not a good start for the discussion.  Asking "if anyone knows" and about "the best place" are not sharp ways to frame your discussion topic.  More specific context and details about what kind of discussion is desired might improve it enough to be on-topic.

Comment: You posted this mathematics question on the meta site attached to the site Mathematics. The meta site is intended for support questions and discussions about the main site. Please post your question on the main site instead: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask.

Comment: I'd suggest you to create your own room to discuss about the book. You could also do what mod quid suggest but since the general math room is very active, i think would lead to distraction.

Comment: @nmasanta, implicitly, I am also asking: Is discussion about a particular book on maths suitable for the main site?

Answer (score 5):

In the SE network, you might try in chat. In the general Mathematics room, or maybe in a thematic room related to the subject of the book.

Generally, the SE sites are not intended for discussion.

If you have a specific question related to a book, this might give an on-topic question.